# Performance benchmark iterating over permutations

Tags: python, performance, permutation

I am trying to optimize the iteration over permutations of objects.
For each pair of two objects an operation is performed. The result gets stored in a dictionary twice: For a x,y key pair and for the y,x key pair to ease access to the results.
This is my code:

```
import timeit
from itertools import permutations

MAX = 100
l2 = range(0, MAX)
l2 = [i for i in permutations(l2, 2)]

l1 = range(0, MAX)

# do the permutations inside two for loops
def f1():
    d = {}
    for x, y in l2:
        if x not in d:
            d[x] = {}
        if y not in d:
            d[y] = {}

    for x in l1:
        for y in l1:
            if x == y:
                # result is not needed
                continue
            else:
                if y not in d[x]:
                    res = x*y
                    d[x][y] = res
                    d[y][x] = res

# use the tuples generated by permutations of itertools
def f2():
    d = {}
    for x, y in l2:
        if x not in d:
            d[x] = {}
        if y not in d:
            d[y] = {}

    for x, y in l2:
        #if x == y:
            # result is not needed
        #    continue
        #else:
        if y not in d[x]:
            res = x*y
            d[x][y] = res
            d[y][x] = res

if __name__ == '__main__':
    res1 = min(timeit.repeat("f1()", "from __main__ import f1",
                        number=1000))
    res2 = min(timeit.repeat("f2()", "from __main__ import f2",
                        number=1000))

    print res1, res2, res1/res2
    # results in e.g. 2.65521230858 3.10015283881 0.856477872748
    # result after update: 3.52828623172 3.2469033563 1.08666191893
```

I am trying to understand why *f1()* takes only ~85% of the time of *f2()*.
According to my understanding *f2()* should be faster as it doesn't need to iterate over the second list.

Can anybody explain why this isnt true here?

**UPDATE**: I just saw that the x == y condition isnt needed for f2 as x is never equal to y here. Also moved the creation of the first level dictionary outside of the for loop to avoid influences from it. Now the speed up is ~8% for f2.

Comment: There is a significant difference in the length of your two lists, l1 and l2. 100 and 9900 respectively. This is most likely why the times for the two functions will be similar.

Comment: If we put the condition `if x not in d:  d[x] = {}` inside the loop `for y in l1` in `f1`, the ratio increases to ~92%, and then if we switch to Python3, it goes to ~98%.

Comment: @RedShift: Yes, this is the intended behaviour. E.g. if you set MAX to 6 and print x, y, res in each line where res is assigned to the dictionary's keys you will see that for both functions the same values are treated.

Comment: [Loop optimization](https://www.python.org/doc/essays/list2str) in Python.

Comment: Note that if you use generators, that is `l3 = (i for i in permutations(l1, 2))`, you will avoid the overhead of creating the entire list at once.